# Update the fields of one struct to another struct

Tags: go, struct

I have a struct:

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName int
    Age int 
    HairColor string
    EyeColor string
    Height string
}
```

And I have a function that takes in 2 parameters, and updates the first Person's fields to the second person's fields:

```
func updateFields(personA *Person, personB Person) {
    personA.FirstName = personB.FirstName
    personA.LastName = personB.LastName
    // Don't want to change Age.
    personA.HairColor = personB.HairColor
    personA.EyeColor = personB.EyeColor 
    personA.Height = personB.Height

}
```

Instead of hard-coding the values to change, how can I loop through the fields and update the first Person to have the same values as the second Person except for the "Age" field?

Comment: You can do `*personA = personB`

Comment: Just edited the question. I need all the fields to be the same except one of them

Comment: `personB.Age = personA.Age` and then see first comment ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For trivially copying every field, you can simply do something like `*personA = personB`. If you need to "not copy" just one specific field (same field every time), you could probably just save that field's value in a separate variable, copy everything with `*personA = personB`, and then copy the value back. But this is only useful for very specific situations. It wouldn't allow for example to have a dynamic set of fields not to copy.

If you want to do it with more flexibility, you can do it using reflection, sample code below.

Notice that there may be a few limitations. Notably, you can only set exported fields. Also, if you don't test for these limitations and accidentally try to set a field that's not settable, or with a value of type that's not assignable to that field, etc, the `reflect` package will happily `panic`. So it's wise to add a lot of checks before you actually `.Set(...)` the field.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Person struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName int
    Age int
    HairColor string
    EyeColor string
    Height string
}

func updateFields(personA *Person, personB Person) {
    // .Elem() called to dereference the pointer
    aVal := reflect.ValueOf(personA).Elem()
    aTyp := aVal.Type()

    // no .Elem() called here because it's not a pointer
    bVal := reflect.ValueOf(personB)

    for i := 0; i < aVal.NumField(); i++ {
        // skip the "Age" field:
        if aTyp.Field(i).Name == "Age" {
          continue
        }
        // you might want to add some checks here,
        // eg stuff like .CanSet(), to avoid panics
        aVal.Field(i).Set(bVal.Field(i))
    }
}

func main() {
    b := Person{
        FirstName: "Bruno",
        LastName:  1,
        Age:       2,
        HairColor: "hello",
        EyeColor:  "world",
        Height:    "tall",
    }
    a := Person{}
    fmt.Println(a)
    updateFields(&a, b)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: Woops! Forgot to add in one more part of the question. edited it above. What if I wanted to update all Fields EXCEPT the Age field?

Answer (score 4):

You can just copy the entire `personB` into `personA` and make a backup of the `Age` field before:

```
func updateFields(personA *Person, personB Person) {
    tempAge := personA.Age
    *personA = personB
    personA.Age = tempAge
}
```